# Static headers and dynamic headers issue in retrofit

Tags: http, header, retrofit2, httpclient, interceptor

**I need help regarding the Java Retrofit request:**

Scenario 1: *I have added an interceptor having few static headers*.

Scenario 2: *While requesting API, sending few dynamic headers also*.

When the request completes, I check request headers like below.

```
response.raw().request().headers()
```

**where I can see the static headers but not the dynamic headers.**

below is the code for Interceptor to set static headers:

```
public class AuthInterceptor implements Interceptor {

    public AuthInterceptor() {
    }

    protected String authtoken;

    public AuthInterceptor(String authtoken) {
        defaultHeader();
        this.authtoken = authtoken;
    }

    public void setAuthtoken(String authtoken) {
        this.authtoken = authtoken;
    }

    private Headers.Builder defaultHeader() {
        final String xUserAgent = Util.SDK_NAME + "/" + Util.SDK_VERSION;
        return new Headers.Builder()
                .add("X-User-Agent", xUserAgent)
                .add("User-Agent", Util.defaultUserAgent())
                .add("Content-Type", "application/json");
    }

    public Headers.Builder addHeader(@NotNull String key, @NotNull String value) {
        defaultHeader().add(key, value);
        return defaultHeader();
    }

    @NotNull
    @Override
    public Response intercept(Chain chain) throws IOException {
        Request.Builder request = chain.request().newBuilder()
                .headers(defaultHeader().build());

        if (this.authtoken != null) {
            request.addHeader("authtoken", this.authtoken);
        }
        return chain.proceed(request.build());
    }


}
```

And Sending dynamic headers like below.

```
    @POST("stacks")
    Call<ResponseBody> create(
            @Header("organization_uid") String orgUid,
            @Body RequestBody body);
```

Comment: Can you post the code you are using to set the headers?

Comment: Added detailed information (code) in the question. Please Verify

Comment: The syntax looks like it should work. Have you printed out the authToken right before the null check, to ensure it is set as expected?

Comment: yes ! the authtoken is working fine with all other static headers. the issue is with the dynamic header I'm sending is not attaching to the request

I can see the request headers via: 
response.raw().request().headers()

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks to me like the problem is in your use of:

```
Request.Builder request = chain.request().newBuilder()
            .headers(defaultHeader().build());
```

If you look at the documentation of the 'headers' method it states: *Removes all headers on this builder and adds {@code headers}.*

Just add each header with addHeader and you should be fine.